# Cloud vendor neutral solution for Security Groups/Firewall rules etc.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, firewall, aws-security-group, network-security-groups

When an application is deployed in cloud, it needs to set Security Groups/Firewall rules, an application can be written to deploy to any cloud vendor.

But how about SecurityGroups/Firewall rules? Application must use firewall rules, but usage leads to vendor locking.

Can there be any cloud neutral solution for Firewall rules?

Comment: My assumption is that you question is about [Amazon EC2 and Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/compute#iaas_comparison) and seems like to be a feature request. So I recommend that you send your feature request to the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) since Stack Overflow is reserved for technical questions.

Answer (score 0):

SPIFFE specification exactly addresses this problem. But, this project seems to be in its inception stage
https://spiffe.io/spiffe/